# What is the potential scope of a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, scope, c++11

A point from ISO draft n3290 section 3.3.9 paragraph 5:

> Because the name of a template parameter cannot be redeclared within its potential
>       scope (14.6.1), a template parameter’s scope is often its potential scope. However,
>       it is still possible for a template parameter name to be hidden;

What does "potential scope" mean in this context? Can anybody provide an example of such?

draft link n3290: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3290.pdf

Comment: Edited the title to actually reflect the topic of your question.

Comment: @Xeo : iam not asking  that? i don't know what actually meant for potential scope?

Comment: Well, doesn't my reformulated question ask exactly for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3.3.1 : The *scope* of a declaration is the
>   same as its *potential scope* unless
>   the *potential scope* contains another
>   declaration of the same name. In that
>   case, the *potential scope* of the
>   declaration in the inner (contained)
>   declarative region is excluded from
>   the *scope* of the declaration in the
>   outer (containing) declarative region.

Normally, this refers to cases like this:

```
void Foo(int i) {
  {
    int i = 5;
    std::cout << i;
  }
  std::cout << i;
};
```

The potential scope of the second `i` is excluded from the scope of the first `i`. In other words, this describes precisely where name hiding applies. The bit you quote says that template names can be hidden, too.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer ,can u able to tell the example for above point?

Comment: See 14.6.1/7 for a commented example, where `class B` is hidden by `A<B>::B`.

Answer (score 2):

From paragraph 3 of the same section:

> The potential scope of a template
>   parameter name begins at its point of
>   declaration (3.3.2) and ends at the
>   end of its declarative region. [
>   *Note*: This implies that a *template-parameter* can be used in the declaration of subsequent
>   *template-parameters* and their default arguments but cannot be used
>   in preceding *template-parameters* or
>   their default arguments. For example,
>
> ```
> template<class T, T* p, class U = T> class X { /* ... */ };
> template<class T> void f(T* p = new T);
> ```
>
> This also implies that a
>   *template-parameter* can be used in the specification of base classes. For
>   example,
>
> ```
> template<class T> class X : public Array<T> { /* ... */ };
> template<class T> class Y : public T { /* ... */ };
> ```
>
> The use of a template parameter as a
>   base class implies that a class used
>   as a template argument must be defined
>   and not just declared when the class
>   template is instantiated. —*end note*
>   ]

Comment: yeah i have seen that point....thats what i am getting doubt about Potential scope(i.e means ...local scope,etc)