# How to deduce C++ return type in template?

Tags: c++, templates, functor, generic-programming, c++03

I have a functor, I want the return type to be deduced automatically. How can I do this?

```
template <typename _ScalarL, typename _ScalarR>
struct Multi
{
    DEDUCEDTYPE operator()(_ScalarL input1, _ScalarR input2) const
    {
        return input1 * input2;
    }
};

int main(){
    Multi<int, double> mt;
    mt(1,2.0);
}
```

how to get the `DEDUCEDTYPE` automatically?

Comment: If you respell `DEDUCEDTYPE` as `auto`, it should already work (provided you're using C++14).

Comment: Note that names starting with underscore-capital are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @KerrekSB I can't use C++11 or upper for a low g++ version.........

Comment: Could you please explain more about "reserved for the implementation"?

Comment: In this context, "reserved for the implementation" means "only compiler vendor can do this, and you can't".

Comment: @NickyC Is it allowed to use _scalar?

Comment: Before c++11 (and so `decltype`), you have to make your own traits, with all possible values.

Comment: I'm not sure if a template parameter is considered "global scope", but if it is, than `_scalar` is reserved as well. The best way I think is to avoid uncertainty and simply use `Scalar`

Comment: Well, you should have specified your version restrictions in the question. @StoryTeller AFAICT the scope of a template argument is between its declaration and the end of the enclosing `template` block, not global, meaning you'd 'only' be hiding any global identifier with the same name - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5987276/2757035 - but I'd say it's best to avoid the potential ambiguity in any case.

Comment: Depending on restrictions, before C++11 there's `__typeof__`. As for `common_type`, it is more or less easy to implement it in C++03 if you have access to TR1's `is_convertible`.

Answer (score 3):

Well I believe that before c++11 you are doomed to provide deduction by hand... You could create helper struct with specializations for that:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct deduce { };

template <>
struct deduce<int, double> {
   typedef double type;
};

template <typename ScalarL, typename ScalarR>
struct Multi
{
    typename deduce<ScalarL, ScalarR>::type operator()(ScalarL input1, ScalarR input2) const
    {
        return input1 * input2;
    }
};

int main(){
    Multi<int, double> mt;
    mt(1,2.0);
}
```

**Edit:**

The more general way of doing it would invoke however creating the hierarchy of priorities of the types that should be considered while deducing result type. Exemplary code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct MoreGeneralNumber { };

template <>
struct MoreGeneralNumber<long>: MoreGeneralNumber<int> {};

template <>
struct MoreGeneralNumber<float>: MoreGeneralNumber<long> {};

template <>
struct MoreGeneralNumber<double>: MoreGeneralNumber<float> {};

typedef char (&yes)[1];
typedef char (&no)[2];

template <bool L, bool R, typename LT, typename RT>
struct MoreGeneral { };

template <bool R, typename LT, typename RT>
struct MoreGeneral<true, R, LT, RT> {
   typedef LT type;
};

template <typename LT, typename RT>
struct MoreGeneral<false, true, LT, RT> {
   typedef RT type;
};

template <typename B, typename D>
struct Host
{
  operator B*() const;
  operator D*();
};

template <typename B, typename D>
struct is_base_of
{
  template <typename T> 
  static yes check(D*, T);
  static no check(B*, int);

  static const bool value = sizeof(check(Host<B,D>(), int())) == sizeof(yes);
};

template <typename L, typename R>
struct Deduce: MoreGeneral<is_base_of<MoreGeneralNumber<R>, MoreGeneralNumber<L> >::value, 
                           is_base_of<MoreGeneralNumber<L>, MoreGeneralNumber<R> >::value, L, R >  {
};

template <typename ScalarL, typename ScalarR>
struct Multi
{
    typename Deduce<ScalarL, ScalarR>::type operator()(ScalarL input1, ScalarR input2) const
    {
        return input1 * input2;
    }
};

int main() {
   Multi<int, double> mt;
   std::cout << mt(1, 2.5) << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: In C++03, there is `boost::result_of` which I would prefer to writing my own stuff.

Comment: @davidhigh Problem is that result_of would require that operator * for primitives would be a function to be provided there in form of pointer... Unfortunately I am not aware of a way of using here `boost::result_of` that would satisfy OP needs...

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't get that, thanks for pointing. If it is so, then there's no benefit, of course. (For simple arithmetic operations, one could however use `boost::common_type`.

Answer (score 3):

> how to get the DEDUCEDTYPE **automatically** [with c++03]?

Automatic type deduction is **not possible with C++03**. As mentioned in other answer, you may have to *manually* create your own deducing specializations.

For **C++11/C++14**:

```
// For C++14, simply `auto` is enough
auto operator()(_ScalarL input1, _ScalarR input2) const
#if __cplusplus < 201402L
-> decltype(input1 * input2) // required for C++11
#endif
```